# SOAP UI - Using the response and saving it as a property then using it as the parameter for next request

Tags: soapui, web-api-testing

I currently have a response which is as follows:

`{"id": "uM5bbONEEKggJw7QY18O5QM0PwA="}`

I am trying to add this as a global property so i can keep using this for other requests. How can i do this using groovy scripting in a way that i can reuse this code in other requests if possible

This is what i tried:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.json.*

def response = context.expand('${Request#Response}')
def JsonSlurperjsonSlurper = newJsonSlurper()
def Objectresult = jsonSlurper.parseText(response)
print Objectresult
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the code below to store the value in global property

```
com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.globalProperties.setPropertyValue("idGlobal",jsonSlurper.id)
```

To confirm if the above command worked on you can goto **File-->Preferences-->Global Properties**

to use this value in any other place you can use the below code

```
 log.info com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.globalProperties.getPropertyValue("idGlobal")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
//imports
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

//grab the response
def ResponseMessage = messageExchange.response.responseContent
//define a JsonSlurper
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText(ResponseMessage)

def id = jsonSlurper.id
```